# Give me more examples using the word 'legerdemain.'

Tags: meaning

I came across the word, 'legerdemain' in the newspaper. This part says about Romney.

...And, his tax legerdemain has made him seem shady.

A dictionary says that it is skill in using your hands to perform magic tricks often used figuratively. I think it is a deceptive way of concealing, hiding, or cheating on others. Where can the word be used? Could anyone give me some examples?

Comment: Have you tried googling the word? You should be able to find some examples among the 512,000 hits.

Comment: Oh, right. I should've really done that first. I'll do that jsut right now. Thank you, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's often used in a political context such as this, with the tone often one of begrudging admiration (you don't approve of what they did, but you admit they did it with skill).

Henry Kissinger was often considered a master of legislative, diplomatic, and oratory legerdemain by admirers and detractors alike, so https://www.google.ie/search?q=legerdemain+kissenger gives us many example sentences.

Because of the skill implied, it can be used with unalloyed admiration in circumstatnces when deception is honourable, most notably war:

> However, Maskelyne's greatest challenge, posed to him by British General Bernard Montgomery, was to devise methods of deception that would mislead German Field Marshall Erwin Rommel as to the time and place of the major British attack across the Alamein line in the fall of 1942. Author David Fisher characterized Maskelyne's response to this challenge as "the greatest bit of Legerdemain in the history of warfare. This was the grand illusion." ([Source](http://ibmring122.000space.com/html/war_wizard.html))